# Radius of convergence of cumulant generating function

Tags: pr.probability, generating-functions, moments, cumulants

Recall that for a random variable $X$ with a moment generating function $M_X(t)$ the cumulant generating function is defined as
\begin{align}
K_X(t)=\log M_X(t) 
\end{align}

The Taylor expansion of $K_X(t)$ is given
\begin{align}
K_X(t)= k_1 t+ k_2 \frac{t^2}{2}+ k_3 \frac{t^3}{3!}+..
\end{align}
where $k_i$ are the cumulants.

My question: Can we determine the radius of convergence of $K_X(t)$ if we know the radius of convergence of $M_X(t)$?

For example, in these [slides](https://cpb-us-w2.wpmucdn.com/sites.wustl.edu/dist/4/2002/files/2019/07/Lecture5.pdf), it is claimed both moments generating functions and cumulant generating functions have the same radius of convergence.

Comment: If $M_x(t)$ converges for some $t$, then $K_X(t)$ is simply computed by the given formula $K_X(t) = \log M_X(t)$. And vice versa, $M_X(t)$ can be computed as $\exp K_X(t)$ if $K_X(t)$ converges. So, the slides are correct.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev  See the answer below.

Comment: Well, the above argument is valid with addition that we want $M(t)>0$ (to be in the $\log$ domain) for convergence of $K(t)$. If this inequality always holds, then the two radii are the same; otherwise the smallest by absolute vale zero of $M(t)$ comes into play.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev  But $M(t)>0$ for all real $t$, right? Can you explain this a bit more.

Comment: For all real $t$ within the radius of convergence of $M$.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev  I don't see why the radius of convergence is relevant here.  $M(t) =E[e^{tX}]>0$ for all $t$ since $e^{u}>0$ for all $u$.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say. If you like Alexandre's answer, just go for it.

Answer (score 4):

Of course, this is not correct. As a simplest example, let
$X$ be a random variable which takes only values $\{0,\ldots, n\}$, then
the moment generating function is a polynomial of $e^t$, of degree $n$, therefore its radius of convergence is infinite. Any polinomial with positive coefficients which add to $1$ can occur.
But $\log M(t)$ has finite radius of convergence
since a polynomial $P$ of degree $n\geq 1$ has some zeros in the complex plane. So $P(e^t)$ also has zeros, unless $P$ is a monomial.

In general, the radius of convergence for $K(t)$ is the distance from
the origin to the closest zero of $M(t)$.